# Maven build fails but Intellij works

Tags: maven, dependencies

I am working on a microservice structure and I have added one new module to one of the microservices and build it on my local machine so it created new jar in my local maven repository. In other microservice, I am using this new module and I added new jira from my local maven repository to the project. So intellij can see new classes in the module and I am able to run my unit and integration tests.

But when I run mvn clean install it gives error which says package not found. So what I am doing wrong and maven build fails?

Answer (score 0):

In the main pom.xml, you need to add modules like below

```
<modules>
<module>artifact-id-of-module-1</module>
<module>artifact-id-of-module-2</module>
</modules>
```

And in the pom.xml of the second module, you need to add dependency like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>parent-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-id-of-module-1</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will enable you to access all the class of module1 in module 2. Please adjust your module name 1 and module name 2 respectively. Running `mvn clean install -U` after this should do the thing.